# AWS DELETE folder request succeeds but the folder is still there

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application that communicates with my Amazon S3 bucket via REST API.  The authentication works correctly and I am able to perform many operations (e.g., create folder, upload file, download file, GET objects).

I have one remaining problem: although my REST requests to delete a folder succeed (i.e., AWS returns a "204 No Content" response), the "deleted" folder can still be accessed via the AWS web console.

Before issuing the DELETE request, I can see via the AWS web console that the folder (and its subfolders and files) exists.  My bucket has versioning DISABLED.

Now the app issues the REST DELETE request:

```
DELETE /App_Root/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: libcurl/7.28.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8j App/2.1.105-Windows
Host: my-company-s3-account.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 18:24:08 +0000
Authorization: AWS [signed string]
```

Here is the response received from Amazon S3:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
x-amz-id-2: 6in0UAKZZWfgw2ifNhLVT8+UhNLGAo/8948L2SUqhg/OB5agr6X8q8ceQ/3Z4emO4n/XgfXqIUo=
x-amz-request-id: 42802B620F593699
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 18:23:44 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

Refreshing the AWS web console shows the deleted folder still exists.  Issuing another GET object request to Amazon S3 shows the folders and files still exist as before.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the fact that folders do not actually exist in S3.

Everything that looks like a folder is only a convenient illusion presented by the console, based in the `/` delimiters in the object keys.

> The Amazon S3 data model does not natively support the concept of folders, nor does it provide any APIs for folder-level operations. But the Amazon S3 console supports folders to help you organize your data.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/about-using-console.html

To delete a "folder" using the API, you have to delete the objects that appear to be "in" it.

So, why don't you get an error in your code?

That's because the `DELETE` REST verb is idempotent.   After your delete request, there isn't an object at the path you deleted, so, technically, you "succeeded," and the operation succeeds no matter how many times you delete something, whether it exists or not.

The console still shows a folder because there are object with that prefix, still in the bucket.

When you delete a folder from the console, the console takes care of the actual deletion of the "contained" objects by sending one or more additional requests to delete the underlying objects.

Note also that there is no need to create a folder before storing objects "in" it using the API.  It will implicitly appear in the console if you create just one object with `/` slashes in the key.

Comment: @sqlbot Your reply is one of the clearest and informative SO replies I've had the pleasure of receiving.  When I grow up, I want to post excellent replies like yours <g>.

Indeed, I implemented the look-and-feel of a classic folder structure in Amazon S3 so (too?) well, I even fooled myself.  Thanks for bringing me back to the fact that everything in S3 is keys, not folders.